# Django - Notification Migrations InconsistentMigrationHistory

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

When I try to makemigrations or migrate my Django project to the database I'm getting the following error:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration notifications.0001_initial is applied before its dependency pecus.0001_initial on database 'default'.

**The solution that works it's to drop the entire database, delete migrations files, "python manage.py makemigrations" and "migrate" again**

**But**, I don't think that this is the right way for solving this. In every commit of our project (I'm working in a development team) we have to do this in our local databases so the project can work.

We are using a MySQL 5.7 database system.

Please, what should  I do to try to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the point of having to delete your database with every commit. Does this mean your database models are changing with every single commit your team makes to your project?

Comment: Yes! But the problem it's just with notifications. The new models are migrating without problems.

Comment: I see. If the problem is just with the notifications model, then you will need to provide some more information.